# Does splitting Inno Setup Pascal Script code to sub functions/sub-procedures impact performace?

Tags: inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

I'm creating all the pages directly on `InitializedWizard` section (they don't have order of creating for Example; `Page2, Page5, Page1`) like

```
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  Text : TLabel;
Begin
  Page2 := CreateCustomPage(Page1.ID, '', '');
  Text := TLabel.Create(page2);
  Text.Left := ScaleX(0);
  Text.Top := ScaleY(35);
  Text.Caption := ''; 
  Text.Parent:= Page2.Surface;

  Page5 := CreateCustomPage(Page4.ID, '', '');
  Text := TLabel.Create(Page5);
  Text.Left := ScaleX(0);
  Text.Top := ScaleY(35);
  Text.Caption := ''; 
  Text.Parent := Page5.Surface;
End;
```

I there is a difference, if I create the pages on separated `procedures`, and then call them in `InitializeWizard` like this?

```
procedure CreatePage1;
var
  Text : TLabel;
begin
  Page2:= CreateCustomPage(Page1.ID, '', '');
  Text := TLabel.Create(Page2);
  Text.Left := ScaleX(0);
  Text.Top := ScaleY(35);
  Text.Caption := 'Tickets Printer'; 
  Text.Parent := Page2.Surface;
end;  

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  CreatePage1();
  CreatePage2();
  CreatePage3();
end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you have some real problem? Or is this just a generic question?

Comment: I had a very bad performance when running the installer and I believed that changing the order in which the pages were created would increase the performance, but 3 minutes ago I solved my problem by changing the order of extraction of the images inserted on the Welcome page (images extracted at the end), I will now remove the question, I am sorry I did not explain at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no practical performance difference between:

```pascal
procedure Master;
begin
  Statement1;
  Statement2;
end;
```

and

```pascal
procedure Child1;
begin
  Statement1;
end;

procedure Child2;
begin
  Statement2;
end;

procedure Master;
begin
  Child1;
  Child2;
end;
```

If that's, what you ask.

Comment: Thank You, that's what I ask.